# Figure changes when loading pdf to inkscape

Tags: r, pdf, svg

I use heatmap.2 in R to draw a figure and save it as PDF format. When I opened the PDF files, it looked good. 
[PDF Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz9oJ.png)
But when I loaded the PDF file into Inkscape. It seemed that the color key is not as bright as what I saw in PDF files. 
[PNG file exported from Inkscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIeMB.png). Please focus on the colorkey. 
Can someone help me on this? 
Thanks.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: Here is the R code I used:
https://github.com/zeamxie/RExampleCode/blob/master/R_code4question/heatmap.2_exp.R

Answer (score 0):

This has probably got something to do with the used colorspace, try changing the colorspace in the pdf-output device with the `colormodel` option.